# Raspberry Pi 2 Server Sending Data to Android Phone Client

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server, raspberry-pi2

I'm hosting a server on my raspberry pi 2, and sending a stream of values between 0 and 360. I'm trying to grab whatever number is just sent on my android phone. Currently, it runs through the ReadServer code once, returns 48 (char 0) and then crashes with an 'unhandled runtime exception'. I'm able to just dummy values and have it work perfectly fine, so I know its something having to do with the client/server side.

Yes I have internet permission specified in my manifest.

**PI**

Server hosted on raspberry pi 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void error(char * msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int sockfd, clisockfd, portno = 5003;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[127];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    /* call socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) { error("ERROR opening socket"); }


    /* initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);


    printf("waiting to bind\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    { error("ERROR on binding"); }


    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = (socklen_t) sizeof(cli_addr);


    printf("waiting to accept\n");
    clisockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    printf("accepted\n");
    if (clisockfd < 0) { error("ERROR on accept"); }

    int heading = 0;
    while (heading < 360)
    {

        bzero(buffer, 126);
        printf("sending\n");
        sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", heading);

        n = write(clisockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

        if (n < 0) { error("ERROR writing to socket"); }
        printf("sending %s\n", buffer);

        usleep(2 * 1000*1000);

        heading = heading + 2;

    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**ANDROID**

Main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String IP_ADDRESS = "x.x.x.x"; // (is an actual address)
final int PORT = 5003;


boolean isManual = true;
RelativeLayout layout_joystick;
JoyStickClass js;
TextView velocityTextView;
Button manualButton;
ImageView compassPhoto;
Wifi wifiController;

ReadServer serverObject;

Timer serverTimer = new Timer();
Handler serverPollHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // set new view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // define buttons/interactions
    manualButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.manual_button);
    Button disconnectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button);
    layout_joystick = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_joystick);
    compassPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCompass);


    // set joystick settings
    js = new JoyStickClass(getApplicationContext()
            , layout_joystick, R.drawable.image_button);

    js.setStickSize(150, 150);
    js.setLayoutSize(500, 500);
    js.setLayoutAlpha(150);
    js.setStickAlpha(90);
    js.setOffset(90);
    js.setMinimumDistance(50);


    // set button listeners
    manualButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleMode();
        }
    });

    layout_joystick.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            return jsOnTouchListener(arg0, arg1);
        }
    });

    disconnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switchToLoadScreen(view);
        }
    });

    // load camera feed
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    velocityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.velocityText);

    serverPollHandler = new Handler(serverCallback);



    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            //connect wifi
            wifiController = new Wifi(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);

            if (!wifiController.Connect()){
                switchToLoadScreen(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
            }
            serverObject = new ReadServer(wifiController.getInputStream());

            serverTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new getFromServer(), 500, 2 * 1000);

        }
    });

    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/cameraFeed.html");

}

Handler.Callback serverCallback = new Handler.Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        velocityTextView.setText("1m/s");
        try {
            serverObject.execute().get();

            int headingToMoveTo = serverObject.getHeading();
            moveCompassTo(headingToMoveTo);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        catch (ExecutionException e) {}

        return true;
    }
};


// move the compass
private void moveCompassTo(float degree) {

    float currentDegree = 0f;

    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree,
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(5);

    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start the animation
    compassPhoto.startAnimation(ra);
    int a = 5;
}



// toggle between manual and autonomous modes
private void toggleMode() {
    if (isManual) {
        // set Autonomous Mode

        manualButton.setText(R.string.manual_text);
        layout_joystick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wifiController.enterAutonomous();
        isManual = false;
    } else {
        // set Manual Mode

        manualButton.setText(R.string.autonomous_text);
        layout_joystick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        wifiController.enterManual();
        isManual = true;
    }

}


// switch between views
private void switchToLoadScreen(View thisView) {

    if (wifiController.Disconnect()) {

        serverTimer.cancel();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(thisView.getContext(), LoadScreen.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
}


// control what moving the joystick does {emitted}
private boolean jsOnTouchListener(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    js.drawStick(arg1);
    if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        //         textView1.setText("X : " + String.valueOf(js.getX()));
        //         textView2.setText("Y : " + String.valueOf(js.getY()));
        //         textView3.setText("Angle : " + String.valueOf(js.getAngle()));
        //         textView4.setText("Distance : " + String.valueOf(js.getDistance()));

        switch (js.get8Direction()){
            case JoyStickClass.STICK_UP:
                wifiController.moveForward();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_UPRIGHT:
                wifiController.moveForwardRight();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_RIGHT:
                wifiController.moveRight();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNRIGHT:
                wifiController.moveBackRight();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWN:
                wifiController.moveBack();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNLEFT:
                wifiController.moveBackLeft();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_LEFT:
                wifiController.moveLeft();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_UPLEFT:
                wifiController.moveForwardLeft();
                break;

            case JoyStickClass.STICK_NONE: // center
                break;
        }
    } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //         textView1.setText("X :");
        //         textView2.setText("Y :");
        //         textView3.setText("Angle :");
        //         textView4.setText("Distance :");
        //         textView5.setText("Direction :");
    }

    return true;
}


public class getFromServer extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        serverPollHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

}


}
```

ReadServer code:

```
public class ReadServer extends AsyncTask {

BufferedReader thisStream;
int heading = 0;

public ReadServer(BufferedReader fromPi)
{
    thisStream = fromPi;
}

public int getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

    //communication from PI
    try {

        if (thisStream.ready()) {

            int read = thisStream.read();
            String t = Character.toString ((char) read);

            if (read > 0) {
                heading =  Integer.parseInt(t);
            }

        }


    }
    catch (IOException e) {}

    return params;
}

}
```

WifiController code:

```
public class Wifi extends AsyncTask {


// THESE MUST BE IDENTICAL TO THE PI CODE FOR CORRECT FUNCTIONALITY
private enum send_modes {
    AUTONOMOUS_FLAG,
    MANUAL_FLAG,
    DISCONNECT_PI,
    MOVE_NORTH,
    MOVE_NORTHEAST,
    MOVE_EAST,
    MOVE_SOUTHEAST,
    MOVE_SOUTH,
    MOVE_SOUTHWEST,
    MOVE_WEST,
    MOVE_NORTHWEST
}
//


private Socket phoneToPiSocket;
private boolean isConnected = false;
private InetAddress piIPAddress;
private PrintWriter piSocketWriter;
private int portNumber;
private BufferedReader fromPi;

public Wifi(String ipAddr, int port) {
    try {
        portNumber = port;
        piIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        piIPAddress = null;
    }
}


@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

    try {
        phoneToPiSocket = new Socket(piIPAddress, portNumber);
        fromPi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (phoneToPiSocket.getInputStream()));
        // piSocketWriter = new PrintWriter(phoneToPiSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        isConnected = true;

    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        isConnected = false;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        isConnected = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        isConnected = false;
    }
    return params;
}

public boolean Disconnect() {
    if (isConnected) {
        try {
            fromPi.close();
            //disconnectFromPi(); // has to happen before writer is closed!
            //piSocketWriter.close();
            phoneToPiSocket.close();
            isConnected = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public BufferedReader getInputStream()
{
    return fromPi;
}

public boolean Connect() {

    // set up wifi connection
    try {
        execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

    }

    if (isConnected) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

boolean isConnected(){
    return isConnected;
}



//communication to PI
public void enterAutonomous()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.AUTONOMOUS_FLAG.ordinal());
}

public void enterManual()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MANUAL_FLAG.ordinal());
}

public void disconnectFromPi()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.DISCONNECT_PI.ordinal());
}

public void moveForward()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_NORTH.ordinal());
}

public void moveForwardRight()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_NORTHEAST.ordinal());
}

public void moveRight()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_EAST.ordinal());
}

public void moveBackRight()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_SOUTHEAST.ordinal());
}

public void moveBack()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_SOUTH.ordinal());
}

public void moveBackLeft()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_SOUTHWEST.ordinal());
}

public void moveLeft()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_WEST.ordinal());
}

public void moveForwardLeft()
{
    piSocketWriter.println(send_modes.MOVE_NORTHWEST.ordinal());
}

}
```

I apologize for how messy / horribly named everything is. Its a work in progress.

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATED INFO:**

The exception i get is:

```
"main@20747" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING 
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:72)
      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

[Picture of frames at crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPzf4.png)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: how? @JohnScattergood

Comment: You wrote: "crashes with an 'unhandled runtime exception'".  So if you can copy and paste the exception into your question, it will help answer it.

Comment: @JohnScattergood see "updated info"